# redirecting stdout to file not working

Tags: c++, file, logging, stdout

```
FILE* logfile;

freopen_s(&logfile, "log.txt", "w", stdout);

printf("test");

fclose(stdout);
```

Im having an odd problem with Visual Studio. When I execute the above code in a console app the log file is written to fine. But when I execute the code in a Win app the log file is always empty.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks fine so I would say the problem is how you are launching the windowed app. You should include that code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows programs do not have a console attached.  Consequently, any stream IO to stdout has no effect.  You can either convert the app to a console app via the SUBSYSTEM switch, or assign a handle to stdout via the SetStdHandle function.

Comment: Ah I see. SetStdHandle seems the way to go. Thanks.